# Cannot assign geometry column using gdf.set_geometry()

Tags: python, dataframe, geometry, geopandas

I am unable to assign an existing column containing geometry data in a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` as an active `geometry` column recognized by geopandas.

Here's my setup:

```py
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame as gdf
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import Point

square = Polygon([[0,0], [0,1], [1,1], [1,0]])
triangle = Polygon([[2,0], [4,0], [3,1]])

figury = gdf([[square, "kwadrat", Point([0.5,0.5])],
                           [triangle, "trójkąt", Point([3,0.3])]],
                          columns=["shape", "name", "center"])
```

Then, when I try to assign (as per [GeoPandas docs](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/data_structures.html#geodataframe)) either `shape` or `center` column as an active geometry using:

```py
figury.set_geometry("shape")
# or
figury.set_geometry("center")
```

I'm getting (quite an ironic) error:

```
AttributeError: You are calling a geospatial method on the GeoDataFrame, but
the active geometry column to use has not been set. 
There are no existing columns with geometry data type. You can add a geometry
column as the active geometry column with df.set_geometry.
```

My question is, "How do I make it work?", or rather "What am I doing wrong?"

An obvious workaround would be to name the column in question `geometry` at creation of `GeoDataFrame`, but that only kind of "works", and also only once.

Any further attempts to assign another column using `gdf.set_geometry`, or renaming another column to "geometry" simply refuse to work (*the column is renamed* to "geometry" but is still not considered an active geometry column by `geopandas`).

Answer (score 2):

Try using the keyword argument in the constructor call to set geometry when you create the geodataframe:

```
figury = gdf(
    [[square, "kwadrat", Point([0.5,0.5])],
    [triangle, "trójkąt", Point([3,0.3])]],
    columns=["shape", "name", "center"], 
    geometry='shape' # Add this
)
```

Then you should be able to set geometry to the other option as needed:

```
figury.set_geometry('center', inplace=True)
figury.geometry

>>> 0    POINT (0.50000 0.50000) 
>>> 1    POINT (3.00000 0.30000) 
>>> Name: center, dtype: geometry
```

Comment: I did try that, and it works as written, however is there any way to make it persistent? When I try `figury.geometry` after this line, the geometry is still the originally assigned one, not the new one.

Comment: The last line in my answer above does not alter the figury object in place, just returns the new geometry. You can reassign it to the figury gdf or add `inplace=True` to the set_geometry() method call to make it persistent in your dataframe. I have edited my answer to show this.